# Get a date (yyyy/mm/dd) from a TextBox in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, date, datetime, textbox

Hi I'm new to C# and in my simple program I need to store some date's in a `DateTime` array so I want to know how to give it a style like `yyyy/mm/dd` from TextBox in C#?

Comment: Your question seems unclear. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Also be specific in terms of what you've already tried. (Can you use a DateTimePicker instead?)

Answer (score 5):

Are you using WinForms? You can use **MaskedTextBox** and set its Input Mask property to Custom yyyy/MM/dd.

Comment: yup, you're right about that, mm is for minute, my bad :)

Answer (score 1):

To Set:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now();
textbox1.Text = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

To Get:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(textbox1.text, ""yyyy/MM/dd"", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: actually it should be: `DateTime.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy")` because '/' represents default datetime separator, or add: `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Comment: You're trying to solve quite opposite task. Read question one more time: OP need to get date from textbox, not set textbox value.

Comment: thanks but your solution just show .now date tox textbox but I want to my writen date in textbox stores in array !!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get date **from** textbox

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(txtBox.Text);
```

or use specific format with `ParseExact(txtBox.Text, "yyyy/MM/dd")`